# React redux state undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to redux and react both. I am trying out my first redux app where my state is getting passed as undefined. Although I searched around the internet to figure the issue but couldn't find out whats the problem.

Below are the code snippets -

Init.js

```
export default function() {
   return {
     isLoggedIn: false,
     username: "admin"
  };
}
```

Reducer.js

```
import initialState from "./init";
let currentState = initialState;
export default function(state = currentState, action) {
  if (action.type === "ONLICK") {
    return state;
  } else {
    return state;
  }
}
```

Index.js

```
const allReducers = combineReducers({
  currentstate: currentState
});

export default allReducers;
```

currentState.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { allreducers } from "./../reducer/index";

class CurrentState extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log("Logged In-" + this.props.isLoggedIn);
    return <div>{this.props.isLoggedIn}</div>;
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    isLoggedIn: state.isLoggedIn
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CurrentState);
```

navbar.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import CurrentState from "./../container/currentstate";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

class Navbar extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>State -</h3>
        <CurrentState />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Navbar.js is where I am displaying the one of the attributes of the state. But in the console when I am trying to print the value it is getting displayed as undefined.

Comment: The code returned from `init.js` is a function. Shouldn't you call the function when you assign `currentState`? `let currentState = initialState()`;

Comment: Also you import "./init" but as title you write "Init.js" is it upper or lower case?

Comment: init.js is in lowercase only in the question it was a typo. Also even if I use let currentState= initialState(), the output remains same.

Comment: Do you import `currentState` in index.js?

Comment: Yes I do else it should say currentState is not defined.

Comment: I was able to resolve this. The mistake was in my container I was using state.isLoggedIn whereas it should be state.currentState.isLoggedIn

Answer (score 0):

You're getting state in wrong way in **mapStateToProps**

> Use

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    isLoggedIn: state.currentstate
  };
}
```

> instead

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
      return {
        isLoggedIn: state.isLoggedIn
      };
}
```

Hope so it will help